# how to extract json data from an public api url?

Tags: json, api, rest, jmeter

I am currently working on a project to test rest API.
How do I access the API data to test it?
Is it possible to extract Json data from an public url and test it??!

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are searching a way to test **API**, It is very simple.

Most of the time, I use to test my api using **Postman- Rest Client**  of **Google chrome**
 [Link of postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en).

You can select method(**GET/POST**) there and also you can add header parameters with your API Url.

And yes, you can extract json Data from public url and you can test it. For that, you can write a code on any programming language.